# how can I pass unsafemutablerawpointer as a C's pointer to objective c++?

Tags: objective-c, swift, opencv, objective-c++, coreml

I'm trying to integrate CoreML model into my app. The output is given by a `MLMultiArray`, but I want the data in it in order to generate an OpenCV matrix. There is a `dataPointer` property in `MLMultiArray`, which is a `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`. How can I pass it as a C's pointer so that I can directly use it to generate an OpenCV matrix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` sounds like a Swift type. Check whether you're viewing the documentation for Objective-C or Swift.

Comment: @Jake Thanks, I have found the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. I don't need to pass the `dataPointer` as C's pointer from Swift to Objective-C++. I can just pass the whole `MLMultiArray` as long as I import  in the obj-c++ file. And then I can directly use `dataPointer` to get a OpenCV Mat